# mediaplayer IllegalStateException no errors on emulator but sometimes crashed on real device

Tags: android, media-player, illegalstateexception

Can any explain why this happenes. I see how mediaplayer good work on emulator, but sometimes crahsed on realdevice.. and i can't fix this because emulator not show error.

code for create mp

```
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setDataSource(myStream);
            mp.prepare(); //also consider mp.prepareAsync().
```

errors which was found by using stacktrace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaPlayer._start(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.start(MediaPlayer.java:798)
    at myApp.activity.com.myApp.play(myApp.java:320)
    at myApp.activity.com.myApp$PlayOn.doInBackground(myApp.java:454)
    at myApp.activity.com.myApp$PlayOn.doInBackground(myApp.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

and line where crashed if follow to myApp.java 454

```
mp.start();
```

Please explain or help me. I will be very happy than

Regards,Peter.

Answer (score 0):

You may only call start when the `MediaPlayer` is [prepared](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepare%28%29) or [paused](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#pause%28%29) as described clearly in the [documenatation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).

There is probably a timing issue here causing the bug to only appear under certain circumstances. I.e if some part of your code runs before another part of the code, your `MediaPlayer` will be in the wrong state and this crash appears. Search for the points where the state transition methods on the `MediaPlayer` are called and see if there is any possibility that they are called in the wrong order.

Seeing that you use futures makes it easy to call methods in the wrong order if you do not pay attention.

Comment: thank for comment.. but im not idiot. and i know all what i need for using media player

Comment: @Peter did you read the part about the threading issue? You dont need to be an idiot for not finding one of those. On the contrary they are usually the hardest bugs to find.